# Exception on dowloading Pdf file in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, pdf, crystal-reports

I am downloading a Pdf file created by crystal report and I download as

```
 ReportDocument repDoc = ( ReportDocument ) System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["StudyReportCrystalDocument"];
        // Stop buffering the response
        Response.Buffer = false;
        // Clear the response content and headers
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        try
        {    
            repDoc.ExportToHttpResponse(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "StudyReport" );
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {
        }
```

Eventhough it is working But I got an exception

base {System.SystemException} = {Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}

Can anyone explain what is the reason for this and how to override the exception?

Comment: It'd be helpful to have the ExportToHttpResponse method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2009/01/unable-to-evaluate-expression-because.html)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the try-catch block.